# Why does my portfolio trend in the opposite direction from the Nifty Index?

Tags: stocks, india, portfolio, market-indexes, nse-india

I have a set of stocks in my portfolio (some are part of Nifty Index, mix of large/mid/small cap), but I observed that **most of the times** when the Index surges, my portfolio drops on that particular day and vice versa, and hence my below questions?

1. Am I holding stocks that are not interesting/good value to other traders?
2. Are my {maybe unpopular} stocks not aligned with the Indian economy?
3. Are the other stocks good compared to what I own in my portfolio?

I don't understand why the stocks in my portfolio are increasing in price when the Index drops.

I see this scenario occurring when index drops up to 0.50 %.

If it drops more than 0.50 %, then my portfolio aligns somewhat with Index.

Comment: If you expect your portfolio to follow the stocks in the Nifty index... then you should buy a fund that tracks the Nifty index, **not** a different set of stocks.

Comment: I don't want my portfolio to follow Index, but, I am trying to understand how to align my portfolio with the overall sector or economy(Index fund in this case probably)

Comment: Given that "overall" and "sector" contradict each other, the phrase "the overall sector" is... confusing.  Are you looking for a set of stocks that track **the whole Indian economy**?

Comment: I am trying to understand on how to trend with the market and not get my portfolio beaten by Index funds.

Comment: Look for a "total stock market" index fund.

Answer (score 5):

Some stocks are not always correlated with the wider market. Effects on the level of a company can cause their stock to underperform or outperform compared to the wider market. For example, if a company had a particularly bad earnings release, it can drop 5%, 10%, 20%, or even more, even if the index (Nifty in this case) is up for the day.

**I see this scenario occurring when index drops up to 0.50 %.**

This can be attributed to the above explanation or just individual variance in daily stock performance.

**If it drops more than 0.50 %, then my portfolio aligns somewhat with Index.**

A significant move in an index can be a result of news about the wider economy as a whole, and everything will just go down in this case of bad news.

**Most of the time, my portfolio drops when the index surges.**

Look into the *beta* of your portfolio. Beta is a measure of correlation as compared to an underlying index. Your broker should provide this data but you can find the individual betas of your holdings  with a Google search. For example, if your stock has a beta of 3, then when Nifty increases/decreases 1%, your stock will increase/decrease 3%. However, if your portfolio's overall beta is *negative* (as seems to be the case here), then it is possible (and maybe even expected) that your portfolio will move in an opposite direction to the index.

Comment: @Entelechois - thanks for your answer, My other question is that could it be that my portfolio has stocks that are not growth stocks based on the [current economic conditions or government visions] of the country